# Selenium - driver.getWindowHandle() - Firefox stops after opening the new window

Tags: selenium, firefox

I'm using `driver.getWindowHandle()` for switching between windows. This is working fine in *Chrome* but in *Firefox* after clicking on the button that opens the new window, the execution doesn't continue, neither stops. How can I resolve it?

Edit :- Code shared in comment -

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.id("mybutton")).click();
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Code:

```
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.id("myButton")).click();      
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String windowHandle : handles) {
        if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            //call methods
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); // cntrl to parent window
```

Comment: you need to share the code that's making you run into problem to let us have a better idea of whats happening.

Comment: The code is the following, after the click on Line 2 it doesn't continue with line 3.Line1: String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
 Line2: driver.findElement(By.id("mybutton")).click();  
 Line3: Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
  //etc

Comment: what shall the line 2 button click do? also line 3 only ensures to get the list of handles nothing else

Comment: I only added the code until the line that is not working. The complete code is working fine on Chrome, it switches from the parent to the child windows. But when I run the same test case with Firefox, it doesn't continue from the line 2 (after clicking). The line 2 opens a new child window. Thanks.

Comment: unless you share the entire code and explain what are you trying to do, people wouldn't be able to help you either. Also what does the button do? Could you share the website link or describe in details please.

Comment: I didn't share the entire code because I thought it is not necessary.The code works totally fine with Chrome, so I don't think is a code problem but a Firefox issue. That code get the parent window, click on a button, after clicking on that button, a new window is open, the testing continue on that new window and after closing that new window, the testing continue on the main window (the one that contains the button).I debugged the code and it stops in Line 2:after opening the new window, the debugging process doesn't continue,it doesn't stop either, but it doesn't jump to the new line.Thanks.

Comment: The code has been added to my question. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. For some reason the getWindowHandles() function returns just one handle instead of two

Comment: It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. WindowHandles doesn't return anything, neither a window..

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium 2.53.1 using firefox 47.0.1 as the WebDriver in Java: You need to open the separate windows/browsers in it's own driver. I have having the same problem.  No matter how many windows or tabs I opened, "driver.getWindowHandles()" would only return one handle so it was impossible to switch between tabs.  I found Chrome worked way better for me.

Once I started using Chrome 51.0, I could get all handles. The following code show how to access multiple drivers and multiple tabs within each driver.

```
// INITIALIZE TWO DRIVERS (THESE REPRESENT SEPARATE CHROME WINDOWS/BROWSERS)
driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
driver2 = new ChromeDriver();

// LOOP TO OPEN AS MANY TABS AS YOU WISH
for(int i = 0; i < TAB_NUMBER; i++) {
   driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
   // SLEEP FOR SPLIT SECOND TO ALLOW DRIVER TIME TO OPEN TAB
   Thread.sleep(100);

   // STORE TAB HANDLES IN ARRAY LIST FOR EASY ACCESS
   ArrayList tabs1 = new ArrayList<String> (driver1.getWindowHandles());

   // REPEAT FOR THE SECOND DRIVER (SECOND CHROME BROWSER WINDOW)

   // LOOP TO OPEN AS MANY TABS AS YOU WISH
   for(int i = 0; i < TAB_NUMBER; i++) {
      driver2.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
      // SLEEP FOR SPLIT SECOND TO ALLOW DRIVER TIME TO OPEN TAB
      Thread.sleep(100);

     // STORE TAB HANDLES IN ARRAY LIST FOR EASY ACCESS
     ArrayList tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver2.getWindowHandles());

     // NOW PERFORM DESIRED TASKS WITH FIRST BROWSER IN ANY TAB
     for(int ii = 0; ii <= TAB_NUMBER; ii++) {
        driver2.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(ii));
        // LOGIC FOR THAT DRIVER'S CURRENT TAB
     }

     // PERFORM DESIRED TASKS WITH SECOND BROWSER IN ANY TAB
     for(int ii = 0; ii <= TAB_NUMBER; ii++) {
        drvier2.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(ii));
        // LOGIC FOR THAT DRIVER'S CURRENT TAB
     }
```

Hopefully that gives you a good idea of how to manipulate multiple tabs in multiple browser windows.